# primeng checkbox with reactive form with array

Tags: javascript, html, angular, radio-button, primeng

I am trying to add my array of object to map the primeng checkbox and would like to get the values for selected check boxes.

I have tried FormControlName but it it's throwing undefined after submitting.

below is the rough code

```
data = [
    { type: dropdown
      text: 'drop',
      num: 1.23,
      options: [
      {
       value=1,
       text= 'drop1
      },{
       value=2,
       text= 'drop2
      }
      ]
    },
    { type: checkbox
      text: 'check',
      num: 1.23,
      options: [
      {
       value=1,
       text= 'check1
      },{
       value=2,
       text= 'check2
      }
      ]
    },
    { type: radio
      text: 'radio',
      num: 1.23,
      options: [
      {
       value=1,
       text= 'radio1
      },{
       value=2,
       text= 'radio2
      }
      ]
    },
  ];
```

Template:

```
<form [formGroup]="group">

  <div *ngFor="let d of data">
  <div *ngSwitchCase = "checkbox">
    <p-checkbox *ngFor="let check of options"  [value]="check.value" [formControlName]="check.text"></p-checkbox>
    </div>
    <div *ngSwitchCase = "dropdown">
  <p-dropdown *ngFor="let drop of options" [value]="drop.value" [formControlName]="d.text"> {{drop.text}}
   </p-dropdown>
  </div>
   <div *ngSwitchCase = "radio">
    <p-radioButton  *ngFor="let radio of options"[value]="radio.value" [formControlName]="d.text"></p-radioButton >
  </div>
  </div>
 </form>
```

How I can get the reference of my control and values the same for drop down and check boxes.

How to get the values for dynamic forms?

Comment: Where is `[ngSwitch]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for reactive dynamic form first thing we have to generate the formGroup base of the form control data

getFormGroup method will return a formGroup object by loop over the data and create a form controls with name base of the `text` value .

```js
getFormGroup() {
    
    const formControls = this.data.reduce( (controls , f:FormControl)=>{

      controls[f.text] = this.formBuilder.control(null);
      return controls;

    },{});

    return this.formBuilder.group(formControls)
  }
```

after we generate the form now we can render the form controls on the template

```js
<form [formGroup]="form">

    <div *ngFor="let d of data">

        <ng-container [ngSwitch]="d.type">

            <label for="">{{d.text}}</label>
            <div *ngSwitchCase="'checkbox'">
                <p-checkbox *ngFor="let check of d.options" [label]="check.label" [value]="check.value"
                    [formControlName]="d.text"></p-checkbox>
            </div>

            <div *ngSwitchCase="'dropdown'">
                <p-dropdown [options]="d.options" [formControlName]="d.text">
                </p-dropdown>
            </div>

            <div *ngSwitchCase="'radio'">

                <p-radioButton *ngFor="let radio of d.options" [name]="d.text" [label]="radio.label"
                    [value]="radio.value" [formControlName]="d.text">
                </p-radioButton>

            </div>

        </ng-container>
    </div>
</form>
```

[**stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-primeng-dynamic-form)

Comment: @ malbarmvi ..sorry for different topic..can you help me to get example for ng-select title for selected option.. I have got example for the getting title for the option but I'm looking for selected item title . J was looking for below example...https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wziwui?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: @atitpatel can you give me more details I don't know what is the problem , I have check the demo but still don't know the problem 

Comment: In this example... stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wziwui?file=src/app/… I select first option.. "Loreum....." after selection ... We can see selected item...When I hover on the selected value... I would like to see the title( as the name is too big and user cant see full value)same as when I  open dropdown options and hover over... I am able to see title... – atit patel 3 hours ago   Delete